# GitLab CE: See own project member permission in private projects

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-8, gitlab-ce

A user can see his GitLab group permissions (if he is a direct group member) on the group overview page - but for the projects overview page the own role / permission level is not listed.

If a user is a member of a GitLab project but not of the corresponding group of the project - how can this user see his project permissions? Is there any way for a user to see his own permissions in a GitLab project? Can such a user see the other participating project members?

GitLab version is `8.5.7 CE`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature was added in the meantime (having GitLab version 10.x while writing this answer). The **members** page of a project now lists the permissions for all members (direct project members and inherited group members).